# jQuery Multiple Hover to Show DIV Refactor

Tags: jquery, hover, jquery-hover

I am attempting to shorten this code with the most elegant solution. I would love some input if anyone can assist. Thank you! I assume there is a better way to go about it. Would having classes toggle work better? Any advice is appreciated. Thank you very much.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".olay-1").hover(function() {
    $(".hpanel-1").fadeIn(500);
  }, function() {
    $(".hpanel-1").fadeOut(500);
  });
  $(".olay-2").hover(function() {
    $(".hpanel-2").fadeIn(500);
  }, function() {
    $(".hpanel-2").fadeOut(500);
  });
  $(".olay-3").hover(function() {
    $(".hpanel-3").fadeIn(500);
  }, function() {
    $(".hpanel-3").fadeOut(500);
  });
  $(".olay-4").hover(function() {
    $(".hpanel-4").fadeIn(500);
  }, function() {
    $(".hpanel-4").fadeOut(500);
  });
});


  <div class="hpanel-1">
      <h2>Hidden Text</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="hpanel-2">
      <h2>Hidden Text</h2>
  </div>
        <div class="hanel-3">
      <h2>Hidden Text</h2>
  </div>
        <div class="hpanel-4">
      <h2>Hidden Text</h2>
  </div>


    <div class="container">

      <div class="olay-1">
        Here is the info
      </div>
      <div class="olay-2">
        Here is the info
      </div>
      <div class="olay-3">
        Here is the info
      </div>
      <div class="olay-4">
        Here is the info
      </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Added the markup above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you always keep that order (olay-i fades hpanel-i), you can use this:

```
<!doctype html><html><head><title>Test</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".olay").hover(function() {
    $(".hpanel").eq($(this).index()).fadeIn(500);
  }, function() {
    $(".hpanel").eq($(this).index()).fadeOut(500);
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="hpanel">
      <h2>Hidden Text</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="hpanel">
      <h2>Hidden Text</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="hpanel">
      <h2>Hidden Text</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="hpanel">
      <h2>Hidden Text</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="container">

  <div class="olay">
    Here is the info
  </div>
  <div class="olay">
    Here is the info
  </div>
  <div class="olay">
    Here is the info
  </div>
  <div class="olay">
    Here is the info
  </div>
</div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Thank you!! That is along the lines of what I was looking for, thanks!!